# ObjectionJs fetch entity with many to many relationship

Tags: sql, objection.js, knex.js

I'm using knex-objection.
I have a simple example of 3 tables:
user, authority_user, authority where "user" and "authority" are joined together witha  many to many relationship.

Relationship code:

```
static get relationMappings() {

    return {
        authorities: {
            relation: Model.ManyToManyRelation,
            modelClass: path.join(__dirname, 'Authority'),

            join: {
                from: 'user.id',
                through:{
                    from: 'user_authority.user_id',
                    to: 'user_authority.authority_id'
                },
                to: 'authority.id'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The relationship works, i have inserted a user with one authority and checked it out.
The problem is that eager loading a user with it's authorities returns an **undefined authorities array** like the following:

```
  User {
id: 2,
username: 'someuser',
email: 'someuser@gmail.com',
password: '$2b$10$DztbTKBMsElxH0kk9nK8x.73bgl3W.rZnhzqFH5XRR2FSkYcROzm2',
is_active: 1,
created_at: '2021-12-28 18:10:30',
updated_at: '2021-12-28 18:10:30',
authorities: [ [Authority] ]
```

}
]

Here the authorities array is undefined whilei can clearly fetch relations and get my user's authorities with : await User.relatedQuery('authorities').for(2) which gives :

```
  sql: 'select `authority`.* from `authority` inner join `user_authority` on `authority`.`id` = `user_authority`.`authority_id` where `user_authority`.`user_id` in (?)'
```

RESULT:  [ Authority { id: 1, name: 'ROLE_USER' } ]

EDIT:
I tried to fetch a user with 2 authorities and this is the output:

```
User {
id: 3,
username: 'test',
email: 'test@gmail.com',
password: '$2b$10$3GWQd5b2.JwIvtyyOi/0zOKogY7kOG2aJhUqdFhlYpFvisPgeI62u',
is_active: 1,
created_at: '2021-12-29 08:42:50',
updated_at: '2021-12-29 08:42:50',
authorities: [ [Authority], [Authority] ]
```

}

it seems like ObjectionJs "knows" about the 2 Authority objections, but they just don't "show up" and the authorities array is still undefined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [withGraphFetched](https://vincit.github.io/objection.js/api/query-builder/eager-methods.html) when querying

```
await User
.query()
.withGraphFetched('[authorities]')
.findById(id)
.throwIfNotFound({message: "User not found."})
.then(async user=> { ...})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. you request works well, i have also tried it with "withGraphJoined" and it works too.